# PYODBC asks for credentials although It is part of my cxn code, how can I have it automatically log in

Tags: python, database, pyodbc

```
import pyodbc

cn = pyodbc.connect(driver ='{NexusDB V3.10 Driver }',server = 'name', DATABASE ='db', UID='usr123',PWD='pass123',)

cn.close()
```

When ran, it prompts me a window to re-enter Username & Password?

I then re-enter usr123, pass123 and it creates the connection.

What Am I doing Wrong or how can I automate the login to the DB

I am working with a very outdated DB the driver is NexusDB V3.10 Driver 32 bit odbc driver.

For Example when I connect my dsn to excel, it does not ask me for credentials.

I've tried connecting directly to the DSN:

```
import pyodbc

cn = pyodbc.connect('DSN = db;UID=usr123;PWD=pass123')

cn.close()
```

But this gives me an error where I have to specify the driver.

Comment: Presumably your actual username is not `'username'` and your password isn't `'password'`. There are values to be replaced by real values.

Comment: In my cxn code I put my actual username and password, the above was just for purpose of the question, and I retype it on the prompted login screen once again, the same credentials. Maybe Im not following you answer.

Comment: You're passing string literals as credentials. The values have nothing to do with any value you set

Comment: Thank you, maybe I am being naive, but I am not following your answer/solution.

Comment: @DannyCabrera - Please [edit] your question to include the ODBC driver you are using along with details about your environment (OS: Windows, Linux, ...; pyodbc version, etc.).

Comment: @GordThompson I have edited the question it is an usual driver, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my code, it mostly remained the same, what I had to do was specify both the DSN & the driver. It turns out that how I was doing it before it was creating a temp DSN instead of using an already established System DSN. The code below fixed it:

```
import pyodbc

cn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=DsnName; DRIVER ={NexusDB V3.10 Driver }; DATABASE =db; 
UID=usr123;PWD=pass123')

cn.close()
```